# A surprising result from Green's theorem

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I use Green's theorem to compute:

$$ \int^{1,3}_{-1,2} y^2 dx+2xy dy $$

and I got 0 as $\partial_x F_2$ cancels out $\partial_y F_1$.

Then I try integrate along the line segment from $(-1,2)$ to $(1,3)$ I got 13.

Could anyone spot what could be wrong using Green's theorem to compute this above integral?

Comment: How are you using Green’s theorem to compute an integral over a path that isn’t a simple closed curve?

Comment: This is a common pitfall to apply Green's theorem. But it somehow becomes much easier to avoid this inadvertent error by thinking Green's theorem as the special case of [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem) which states "The line integral of a vector field over a **loop** is equal to the flux of its curl through the enclosed surface."

Answer (score 3):

Green's theorem only applies to simple closed curves, that is, curves that do not cross themselves and are closed. A line segment is not a simple closed curve.